# CAD file mismatch?

Tags: coordinate-system, autodesk

I received a drawing from my client, that they are mentioned co-ordinates value as 6 digits, but i am identity the real value its showing 9 digits.

Can you clarify what type of issue it is, and how I can clear this?

Example:

Point Co-ordinates- 235000 E 358600 N

When we check point identity in CAD (Command-"ID")- 235000000,358600000

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like an issue with units/scale. You could fix this manually by selecting everything in the drawing from your client, and scaling it by a factor of 0.001, using 0,0 as your base point.

Comment: No problem @Pramachandran . Please mark my answer as accepted if it has fixed your issue.